# Voice Recognition SDK/API and Windows 8 Store App (C++)

Tags: c++, windows-8, sdk, voice-recognition

I'm currently trying to find a SDK or API that I can integrate into a Windows 8 Store App (C++). I have found several but they either require desktop APIs not accessable in Store Apps or is only for C# (Such as Bing Voice Recognition, which would be perfect if it was available for c++). I know there is minimal support for what I'm asking, but I've searched extensively so any help/suggestions on what to try or to use for very basic voice to text would be tremendously helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a Windows 8 Store App (C++), the best option I found for using voice recognition is to use the AT&T Speech API. The C# have an SDK, but for C++ you can POST to their server using OAuth2 and get a JSON response back with the speech transcribed.